# Creating Enumerator Field in Oracle using values from another table

Tags: oracle, constraints

Greetings Fellow SOFs,

My application has a lot of tables. And each table has 0/n number of Enumerators. Everything was going nice and bubbly, then all of a sudden my client now wants to move his data to Oracle(They had some native db till then.) Now we have managed to create the SQL for the tables that we have but were clueless with the Enumerators.

I made a sacrifice to the Lord Internet(which basically meant me not looking at FB for like 1-2 hours) and found out that for oracle we can use :

```
Column_Name Data_type(size)(Check In(<Possible Values>)).
```

Looking at this closely I found that it would be better if we create tables for enumerators and use those tables as a constraint while inserting values. Something like

Table Enumerator has 2 fields ID and Enumerator Values

Table My_Table has a Name column which will only accept values which are present in the Enumerator Table.

Reasons :
1. Most of the Enumerators are repeated across different tables.
2. If the client were to update any enumerator table, we don't want them to go back and change all the other table as well.

I am looking at other solutions as well. But , I would be grateful to thee wise men if thee could guide me on my journey.

Found the Solution to the null Problem as well :D... And Now I cna insert either an empty string (or) any one of the values from the table:

```
GOT THE SOLUTION :D
```

Mixed them both (i.e) CHECK IN as well as Constraint :D

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE1"
("ID" number(11) not null,
"STATUS" varchar2(12) Check(STATUS IN('')),  << -- Did the trick,
FOREIGN KEY("STATUS") REFERENCES MY_ENUM3("VALUES"),
primary key ("ID"));
```

Comment: Maybe a foreign key would work for you in this situation.  You would have to have a table for each type of lookup information, but if you needed to change the lookup values you'd just have to update the lookup table and not alter all the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use referencing constraints for that as in below example:

```
SQL> create table enumerator1( id number constraint enum_pk primary key, name varchar2(100) );

Table created.

SQL> create table t2( id number, enum1_id number constraint enum1_ref references enumerator1 );

Table created.

SQL> insert into enumerator1 values ( 1, 'LABEL 1' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values ( 200, 2 );  <== DOES NOT EXIST (YET)
insert into t2 values ( 200, 2 )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST1.ENUM1_REF) violated - parent key not found


SQL> insert into enumerator1 values( 2, 'LABEL 2' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t2 values ( 200, 2 );   <== NOW IT'S OK

1 row created.
```

Comment: Awesome man... It worked...

But now it like I also have to store empty strings...And I can't store empty strings in a primary key column and if no primary key then no referencing :(.

I was thinking, is there any way we can say to Oracle 

"Dude, for this column the values can either be 'NULL' (or) any one of the values from the other table i linked you with"?

Comment: It works. You can say, I have no value: 
    insert into t2 values ( 400, null );